# Tomcat Error 404 in Eclipse but it worked before

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

I understand that many people have mine problem, but the causes may be different, in fact I have not solved looking at other solutions. To be noted that initially my application tests worked!! [run as -> server (after I configure the server)]. Days ago, I move the Tomcat's folder in another root, and then, after that, there was an error for the root. I resolved this step copying tomcat's folder in the old root. But now, whe I run my application as a server, there are "HTTP Status 404 - " with no message and the descripton: "The requested resource is not available.". Moreover, in the console there are this text copyed in pastebin.com:

http://pastebin.com/kv5H2MrJ

Somebody can help me? Please
Thanks

Comment: This is the screenshot of the problem http://imgur.com/jbvaonV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you just cannot access files and (sub)folders in the `WEB-INF` folder directly, the servlet engine (Tomcat in your case) just won't allow you to do that. That is by specification.

Second, `*.java` files are not to be accessed directly, they are to be compiled and deployed.

Third, and most important: get back to the basics, and read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html). Or at least [this shorter one](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).